# Why did activating the Conda environment fail？

Tags: anaconda, zsh, git-bash, oh-my-zsh

Window11；
Default terminal is git-bash,
with zsh and oh-my-zsh;
https://dominikrys.com/posts/zsh-in-git-bash-on-windows/

But `conda activate` faild，

```bash
 ~/Desktop  conda activate                                                                  
__conda_exe:1: no such file or directory: /cygdrive/d/Anaconda3/Scripts/conda.exe
```

I dont know what is cygdrive and where it from?

Please.

I use `conad init --all`

cmd is ok;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRgHt.png)

but git-bash still not ok;

I use `where bash` & `where conda`, output:

```
 ~/Desktop  where python                                                                         
/d/Anaconda3/python
/c/Users/xhang/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python

 ~/Desktop  where conda                                                                               
conda () {
        \local cmd="${1-__missing__}"
        case "$cmd" in
                (activate | deactivate) __conda_activate "$@" ;;
                (install | update | upgrade | remove | uninstall) __conda_exe "$@" || \return
                        __conda_reactivate ;;
                (*) __conda_exe "$@" ;;
        esac
}
/d/Anaconda3/Scripts/conda
```

Answer (score 1):

Good afternoon!

I got a problem like yours after installing Anaconda 3 2023.03-1 and after upgrading conda to version 23.5.0. I use the git-bash shell, under Windows 10.

I tried several solutions, but only one turned out to work - I need to change `\...\anaconda3\etc\profile.d\conda.sh` in two places, adding the option (Run `cygpath --help`)

> -m, --mixed like --windows, but with regular slashes (C:/WINNT )

for `cygpath` -> `cygpath -m`.

And, of course, in yours `.bash_profile` should be a string:

`eval "$('/.../anaconda3/Scripts/conda.exe' 'shell.bash' 'hook')"`

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

MikVVI's answer is entirely correct but a little unclear, so I'll just re-explain.

This problem seems to happen when updating to recent versions of conda on Windows. Bash and Git-bash seem to be unable to find the anaconda3 install dir due to inconsistent use of forward- and back-slashes in conda.sh.

To correct this, find your conda.sh file. It's in `...\anaconda3\etc\profile.d`. In conda.sh, there should be two lines that call `cygpath`. For both lines, replace `cygpath` with `cygpath -m`.

Hope this helps.